# The Earth's Magnetic Field and the Apparent Contradiction with Geographic Poles

Tags: magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

"Regarding the Earth's magnetic field generation, it is said to be a result of the rotation of molten materials in the Earth's outer core, which generates electric currents. We know that the Earth rotates anticlockwise, so assuming the Earth's rotation creates a loop of current flowing (due to the rotation of molten iron and nickel) in the same direction as its rotation, we can apply the right-hand thumb rule to predict that this current flow would produce a north pole above the Earth and a south pole below it. However, this appears to contradict the fact that the Earth has its South Pole near the geographic North Pole.

Can you explain this apparent discrepancy between the direction of Earth's magnetic field and the geographic poles?"

Comment: The way the core creates a magnetic field is complicated and not fully understood. It involves convection currents and is not simply connected to the rotation of  the Earth. The magnetic field periodically reverses i.e. the poles swap round, so it cannot be simply related to the rotation.

Comment: Where is the origin of the quoted text?

Comment: Would first have to demonstrate an understanding that this is not just ions and electrons rotating; that neutral atoms in circular orbits will not generate a magnetic field, due to cancellation. A successful model needs to be physically plausible.

Comment: Overall, the Earth is electrically neutral. If the geomagnetic field was created by charges being carried by the rotation of the Earth, there would have to be negative charges near the crust and positive charges near the core.